# Count non-zero elements in every row of matrix

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix

I am using MATLAB. I have a `8x1000` matrix, and I want a program that will give me a `8x1` matrix, where each entry counts the number of non-zero entries in the corresponding row of the `8x1000` matrix.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can [**`sum`**](http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sum.html) up the non-zero elements in every row, by simply converting the data to logicals before.

```
%// example data
A = randi(10,8,1000)-1;

%// count sum up non-zeros in every row
result = sum(logical(A),2)
```

---

```
result =

   904
   897
   909
   895
   885
   901
   903
   873
```

Comment: A = normrnd(1,1,8,1000)
B = sum(logical(A),2)

Comment: @HarshavardhanThyagarajan ?

Answer (score 5):

You can use `matrix-multiplication` -

```
out = (A~=0)*ones(size(A,2),1)  %// A is the input matrix
```

Answer (score 0):

A more esoteric version could use [`accumarray`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html) and [`bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) with [`nnz`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/nnz.html) as the function to apply the values to for each column / group of the input matrix `A`.  Not as efficient as using `sum` and matrix multiplication, but still a method to think about :):

```
B = bsxfun(@times, 1:size(A,1), ones(size(A,2),1)).';
out = accumarray(B(:), A(:), [], @nnz);
```